# BiSupplier in Java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface, supplier

I have seen `BiConsumer`, `BiPredicate`, `BiFunction` but not `BiSupplier` or similar. I tried the below code but got an exception saying:

> "Multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in BiSupplier".

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BiSupplier<T, R> {

    /**
     * Gets a first.
     *
     * @return a first
     */
    T getFirst();


    /**
     * Gets a second.
     *
     * @return a second
     */
    R getSecond();
}
```

Can some please help me with this.

Comment: You cannot have more than one method in a functional interface.

Comment: so what I need to do to achieve the similar use case

Comment: Not really enough details to understand what you're really trying to do, but typically this sort of thing is handled with a `Pair` class or a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 13):

The concept of `Function` (`Predicate` or `Consumer`) is different from `Supplier`.

A simple explanation:

- `Function` transforms 1 input to 1 output. `BiFunction` transforms 2 inputs.  So theoretically, there can be `TriFunction` etc...
- `Predicate` works the same as `Function` but the output is always `boolean`.
- `Consumer` consumes 1 input and doesn't return anything (`void`). `BiConsumer` consumes 2 inputs. So theoretically, there can be `TriConsumer` etc...

Now, `Supplier`. The `Supplier` turns nothing (0 inputs) into an output. Notice the functional interfaces above provide either *one* (`Function` and `Predicate`) or *none* (`Consumer`) output.

`Supplier` creates something from *nothing*; as you know, it's impossible to have more than one return type. Theoretically `BiSupplier` would mean something like *"Create something from two nothings"* which in Java context makes no sense (however, "one nothing" does: `Supplier<String> supplier = () -> "Hi";`).

You can understand `Supplier<T>` as `Function<Void, T>` (it doesn't work in practice, but the principle is the same). Now, `BiSupplier<T>` would be `BiFunction<Void, Void, T>` which really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

A `BiSupplier` simply wouldn't make sense. Methods return a value of a single type in Java.

So you should simply create a class holding the two values and return that:

```
class MyValue<T, R> {
    private final T first;
    private final R second;

    // constructors, getters.
}
```

And then just use `Supplier<MyValue<T,R>>` instead of creating a new functional interface.

Comment: if `Supplier<MyValue<String, String>>` is in the function parameter, how do we pass the values

Comment: The `MyValue` class needs constructors and getters. If I understand you correctly, you would call the function with `myFunction(() -> new MyValue<>(stringA, stringB))` or something like that, depending on how you're sourcing the values. But that constructor must first be declared to initialize the values.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong, you have annotated the interface with FunctionalInterface but it has got two abstract methods.